# sharing item when gridview item is clicked

Tags: c#, gridview, uwp, windows-phone

I am new to uwp. I wants to get the share option when someone click on gridview item but getting error in item. I thik I have not used it properly. so help me out in it.

.xaml

```
  <GridView x:Name="gridview1" ItemClick="itemclicked">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding image}" Width="120" Height="120" Margin="2"></Image>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>

    </GridView>
```

.cs

```
    loadData();
    DataTransferManager datatrnsfermanager = DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView();
    datatrnsfermanager.DataRequested += new TypedEventHandler<DataTransferManager, DataRequestedEventArgs>(this.shareimagehandler);


    private async void shareimagehandler(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataRequest request = e.Request;

        request.Data.Properties.Title = "Share image";

        DataRequestDeferral deferral = request.GetDeferral();
          try
            {
                   request.Data.SetBitmap(item);
            }
            finally
            {
                deferral.Complete();
            }


    }

private void itemclicked(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = gridview1.SelectedItem;
        DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI();
    }
```

I am getting error in

```
request.Data.SetBitmap(item);
```

in the item

```
The name 'item' does not exist in the current context
```

Comment: Ehh what is the error?

Comment: I am getting error in this line
 request.Data.SetBitmap(item);
The name 'item' does not exist in the current context

Comment: I need to see what the error is and on what line otherwise we can't help

Comment: Does this happen as the application is running or when you try and build it?

Comment: when I try to start debugging the application. I think it is not the correct method that's why I am getting error

Comment: What is the name of your class?

Comment: class 1. I am getting the content correctly in gridview but unbale to link the clicked item in gridview to show share via option.

Comment: So without seeing more code or the stack trace I'm not sure how anyone can debug this. This question is way to broad. You haven't made clear if it's a runtime error or a compile error. What line is the error that you get happening on? Is it an output window error?

Comment: its a compile time error. whenever I use "item" in request.Data.SetBitmap() it throws error

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are seeing

```
The name 'item' does not exist in the current context
```

is because you're attempting to access a local variable outside of its scope.

Local variables [(see this tutorial)](https://www.google.com/#safe=off&q=local+variables+tutorial+c%23) can only be accessed inside of their "scope". A variables scope is defined by where you put the variable and its access modifiers.

For example, your problem is that you're attempting to access the locally scoped variable "item" outside of the function it is defined in.

```
public static void FunctionOne(){
    string localToFunctionOne = "This variable can only be used inside of Function One";
}

public static void FunctionTwo(){
    string localToFunctionTwo = "This variable can only be used inside of Function Two";
}
```

In the above example you can only use these variables inside of the functions they are declared inside of.

If I attempt to access `localToFunctionOne` inside of `FunctionTwo` then I will get `The variable localToFunctionOne does not exist in the current context`

This is the scenario that you have created and is the reason you are getting this error.

In order to resolve this there are a couple different paths you can take. However I think the path you're going to want to take is to create a variable that is scoped to your class.

```
 public static class MyVariableExampleClass{

   public static string globalVariable = "All functions in this class can see this variable";

   public static void FunctionOne(){
       string varibleForFunctionOne = globalVariable;
    }

   public static void FunctionTwo(){
       string varibleForFunctionOne = globalVariable;
   }
}
```

As you can see from this example you can access the class scoped variable named "globalVariable" from both functions.